# Moviemasher file upload process stucks at 51%

Tags: php, angular-moviemasher, moviemasher

I am working with [angular-moviemasher](https://github.com/moviemasher/angular-moviemasher).

I have configure all settings mentioned in doc. I have configured `movimasher.ini` file and aws setup.

Initially I was faced an issue regarding authentication but after editing [authutils](http://angular-moviemasher/app/php/include/authutils.php) file, I am able to solve that issue but now uploading process stucks at 51%

[image]

It is running infinite ajax shows status `"Queued"`.

File is uploaded successfully at s3 bucket. But here process stucks.

I am not getting uploaded image preview.

**After Debug**:-
I have found that `.json` file is not write at its destination path. that's why this uploading process stucks. I have no idea why this json file is not there.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you find a solution? I have the same problem

Comment: Nope. I continued with the older version at that time.

Answer (score 1):

Try following steps:

Start Movie Masher:

```
sudo docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name=angular_moviemasher moviemasher/angular-moviemasher

sudo docker run -d -t --volumes-from=angular_moviemasher --name=moviemasher_rb moviemasher/moviemasher.rb process_loop
```

Find docker-compose.yml in config/docker/composer folder, then:

```
cd /var/www/html/angular-moviemasher/config/docker/composer
sudo docker-compose up -d
```